# Igualar conteúdo de dois objetos

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflexão

Uso o método abaixo para atualizar uma determinada tabela:

```
public int alteraBem(tb_bens itemBem)
{
    try
    {
        using (GestaoAtivoEntities db = new GestaoAtivoEntities())
        {
            var bem = db.tb_bens.Where(v => v.int_id_bem.Equals(itemBem.int_id_bem)).FirstOrDefault();

            bem.txt_tag_rfid = itemBem.txt_tag_rfid;
            bem.txt_codigo = itemBem.txt_codigo;
            bem.txt_descricao = itemBem.txt_descricao;
            bem.txt_modelo = itemBem.txt_modelo;
            bem.int_id_local = itemBem.int_id_local;
            bem.int_id_obra = itemBem.int_id_obra;
            bem.int_id_proprietario = itemBem.int_id_proprietario;

            ..... aqui vão os campos restantes......


            db.SaveChanges();
```

Teria como criar um método para igualar o conteúdo dos objetos de forma dinâmica, sem precisar ser feito manualmente um a um, com reflection ou algo parecido?

Pode até parecer mais complicado criar um método do que mover linha a linha, mas gostaria de algo assim `IgualarConteúdo(origem, destino)`.

Estou usando classes geradas pelo EntityFramework através do banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Existe uma forma simples de 'Injetar' informações de um objeto para o outro, existe uma API  chamada ValueInjecter, que faz o que você quer.
De modo simples, o ValueInjecter verifica quais campos possuem mesmo nome entre dois objetos para depois transferir seus valores para um objeto.

Exemplo de uso:

Incluir o namespace da API.

> using Omu.ValueInjecter;

Após isso, injetar as informações através da extensão InjectFrom.

```
objetoQueIraReceberOsDados.InjectFrom(objetoQueJaPossuiOsDados);
```

De qualquer forma, há exemplos do que mais se pode fazer com ele em  https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter

Comment: Valeu, bem simples, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei como você está lidando com concorrência no seu projeto, mas não me parece ser a forma mais seguro o jeito que você está fazendo.

Se você está trabalhando em um ambiente multiusuário e várias pessoas pegam o mesmo registro (quase) ao mesmo tempo, demorarem um tempo para atualizar, se você não está lidando com a concorrência, a última pessoa que salvar vai sempre ganhar das outras.

Mas voltando para sua pergunta, seu objeto (row) deveria estar `Untracked`.
A melhor maneira de fazer isso talvez não seja obtendo o objeto novamente, setando coluna por coluna e depois salvando, seria melhor pegar entidades sem tracking. [Este artigo é ótimo para explicar maneiras como fazer isso.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

```
  // quando obter a entidade, obtenha assim....
  var entidadeOrinal = Context.MinhaColecao
                              .AsNoTracking()
                              .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 1);

  // (...)
  // aqui você deixa ser usado no seu MVC, WPF... 

  // na hora de salvar, faça isso (sem copiar)
  Context.MinhaColecao.Add(originalEntity);
  Context.SaveChanges();
```

O truque aqui é fazer o contexto não realizar o tracking das modificações. Ele vai achar que é uma entidade nova, porém modificada. O legal disso é que ele vai acabar descobrindo todos os objetos associados (tabelas-filha) e atualizando todas elas no banco também.

Eu não entrei em detalhes de concorrência aqui, mas acredito que seria importante você dar uma investigada. Se o sistema for multiusuário, ou ele irá falhar constantemente ou existirá uma perda contínua de informação.

**EDIÇÃO**

Fazendo uma pesquisa, achei essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185155/cloning-data-on-entity-framework

Existem duas maneiras apontadas para fazer a cópia.

1. **Serialização**

   ```
     private static T DataContractSerialization<T>(T entidade) {
         DataContractSerializer dcSer = new DataContractSerializer(entidade.GetType());
         MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

         dcSer.WriteObject(memoryStream, entidade);
         memoryStream.Position = 0;

         T entidadeCopiada = (T)dcSer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
         return entidadeCopiada;
     }
   ```
2. **Reflection** - Neste caso, é necessário acompanhar o artigo: http://blogs.msmvps.com/matthieu/2008/05/31/entity-cloner/

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Vou pesquisar sobre concorrência e Untracked. Agora mesmo não sendo uma boa prática o exemplo postado, teria como igualar os objetos sem ser item a item? Só por curiosidade mesmo.

Comment: @JotaJotaJota acho que a ideia do código que eu passei seria justamente não fazer essa cópia, sabendo que você está usando um método para altera entidades. No exemplo acima você precisaria alterar a forma como você obtém o objeto antes de ser editado (em algum lugar que você faz o bind ou obtém as informações que não está detalhado no código acima) e alterar sua função "alterarBem" para usar as linhas acima sem precisar fazer a cópia. Mesmo assim encontrei um artigo bom sobre um cara que fez uma função que faz isso, mas internamente no .Net você não achacará nenhuma forma simples de fazer.

Comment: Já vou alterar meu post acima com essas informações. O mais complicado não é simplesmente copiar as colunas em si, mas tratar casos com tabelas filhas, o que o código acima já lidaria mais fácil (exemplo uma entidade com de "bens" com uma tabela filha de "tags" para esse bem).

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado! Vou pesquisar mais e refinar a forma com esta implementado.